# How to change the size of a pyplot scatterplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to change the size of the delimiters of a scatter plot. I need to compare plots and they should all be at the same size, i.e., starting in the same point and ending at same size.

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another plot is

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

And I wish the they be at the same ratio

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the same ratio"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1: subplots**

If you do it as subplots you can share an axis, so they will have the same ratio (scale of axes). Here an example:

```
x=np.random.random((2,20))
>>> x[1,:]*=5
>>> x
array([[0.61385822, 0.06513556, 0.38509674, 0.88475931, 0.61135633,
        0.52850788, 0.28874746, 0.31957553, 0.56352545, 0.73032793,
        0.33251703, 0.46145744, 0.85718266, 0.9245014 , 0.82680079,
        0.64086966, 0.34268507, 0.16287025, 0.75205862, 0.83800607],
       [2.33122874, 0.85485611, 3.22991163, 3.49787662, 4.15323232,
        2.3525812 , 3.42487024, 2.88836999, 4.6458569 , 3.0970779 ,
        1.11708794, 1.43842651, 3.21363567, 0.22537731, 4.30038695,
        2.18049717, 2.41325285, 4.75072423, 1.66524457, 3.714594  ]])
>>> y=np.random.random((2,20))
>>> y
array([[0.56533792, 0.08718218, 0.44651916, 0.71774735, 0.97279402,
        0.55520593, 0.65698023, 0.74630129, 0.02921527, 0.0346008 ,
        0.16860719, 0.4033271 , 0.65322063, 0.07031113, 0.11294362,
        0.01561782, 0.46711258, 0.95043895, 0.41240197, 0.48960332],
       [0.13080883, 0.74344444, 0.42144694, 0.19517648, 0.40808507,
        0.73776604, 0.16057131, 0.78187482, 0.47684809, 0.7813126 ,
        0.02526416, 0.5067928 , 0.94726587, 0.76381176, 0.06206742,
        0.34659303, 0.28615481, 0.93999695, 0.37723651, 0.63998848]])
>>> ax=plt.subplot(121)
>>> plt.scatter(x[0,:],x[1,:])
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f84a1e72950>
>>> plt.subplot(122,sharex=ax,sharey=ax)
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f84a1e72f50>
>>> plt.scatter(y[0,:],y[1,:])
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f84a1dfaa50>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: two plot on the same graph]

**Version 2: scaled independent graphs**

However, if you need independent graphs with the same scale, you can request ymin,ymax xmin,xmax of each plot and set them back. Something like this:

```
plt.scatter(x[0,:],x[1,:])
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f84a0dd3ed0>
>>> xmin,xmax = plt.xlim()
>>> ymin,ymax = plt.ylim()
>>> plt.show()
>>> plt.scatter(y[0,:],y[1,:])
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f84a0d09410>
>>> plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)
(0.015514037327494477, 0.9741229215679024)
>>> plt.ylim(ymin,ymax)
(-0.00981860392769604, 4.985920150990175)
>>> plt.show()
```

In this case you will have two figures, but with the same scales.
[image: one image]
and
[image: Another one]

Answer (score 1):

You need to plot graphs that share the x and y axis with one another. In the example below, `x` has 100 data points ranging from 0 to 100 while `y` has 150 data points ranging from 0 to 50.

```
x = np.random.randint(0,100, size=100)
y = np.random.randint(0,50, size=150)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, sharey=ax1, sharex=ax1)
#ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.scatter(range(100),x)
ax2.scatter(range(150),y, color='darkorange')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also define explicit limits for `x` and `y` axis.

```
yaxis_min, yaxis_max = (min(x.min(), y.min()), max(x.max(), y.max()))
xaxis_max = max(len(x), len(y))
```

Then you can plot them individually as well like this:

```
plt.scatter(range(len(x)),x)
plt.xlim([xaxis_min, xaxis_max])
plt.ylim([yaxis_min, yaxis_max])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Similarly for another variable:

```
plt.scatter(range(len(y)),y, color='darkorange')
plt.xlim([xaxis_min, xaxis_max])
plt.ylim([yaxis_min, yaxis_max])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]